# What can I do with a leopard?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So, a few years ago I bought this leopard from an elven caravan, hoping that I could train it as a war animal and post it to guard the entrance to my fort.  I saw later [on the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Leopard) that leopards are only trainable by the Dungeon Master, so that's not going to happen.  So, what can I do with it?  Let it wander around being awesome?  Make some delicious leopard steaks?

Comment: Have you considered a [NoExotics](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=59411.0) mod?

Comment: Hmm, maybe once I get a Baron.  I'm trying to play as vanilla as possible, but that does seem like a good workaround for the broken functionality.

Comment: "Mod" is probably an overstatement. It's just a program to automate editing one's RAWs. I've written one myself, in Ruby, actually. It doesn't add anything that wasn't already possible in the game (in past versions, anyway).

Comment: Oh, I get what it does.  I'm just saying that, if this version were working as intended,  I would be able to tame the leopard once I got a Baron, so I'll feel better about using it then.  However, I definitely understand that NoExotics makes pretty minor changes to the game.  None of this is supposed to sound judgmental, by the way :P, and I think that's a good idea.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand why you were waiting on getting a Baron before. Now I got ya!

Comment: Feed undesirable dwarfs to the leopard. Add [tag:murder] tag to question. Profit.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Alas, the elves sell only 'tame' leopards.

Comment: So it turns out leopards are __trainable__ if they're already tame, but not __tameable__.  I was __all confused__.  To be fair, the wording on the wiki page is ambiguous.  Anyway, my leopard just got trained into a war leopard, so murder time is soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from breeding it for food (which would require you to acquire another animal of the opposite gender, obviously) and outright butchering like any other animal, and assuming without modding anything, your options are limited to:

- Animal guards, mostly for thief detection. Chain it up near an entrance or main walkway.
- Bait for ambushes, chaining it up somewhere near the map edge and in safe distance from your main (closed off) entrance.
- [Animal watchtower](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=79133.0), since they don't need pasture space.
- Pets, if you have any dwarves who love leopards. Might not be the best idea if you have any who *hate* leopards. Same goes for using it as part of a zoo.
- Cave exploration, dropping it down the caves without any way to come back to the main living area. Use small meeting space designations to guide it around. Being a leopard, it might even get rid of some *undesirables* down there.

(**Version** 0.31.25)

Comment: I __did__ just find my first cavern, so that sounds like a pretty good idea.  All the rest are very useful too.